# How to shard cadence matching service?

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

If I use mysql as database for cadence, I know if sharding is 100, there are 100 table that bound to history service in cadence.
My question is that in this case, all tastList in matching service, will only use one table?
How do sharding databse for matching service?

If all taskList write into the same table, is it enough?

Answer (score 2):

To scale the amount of data, you need to use partitions: same table but different machines will host different partitions.

To scale matching service to keep up with number of polls, you need to use [scalable tasklist](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/maintain/#scale-up-a-tasklist-using-scalable-tasklist-feature)